# Por que ao consultar o firebase através do snapshot, está retornando que maps não é uma função?

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.ref = firebase.firestore().collection('boards');
    this.unsubscribe = null;
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        boards: []
    };
componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.ref.onSnapshot(this.onCollectionUpdate);
}
onCollectionUpdate = (querySnapshot) => {
    const boards = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const { title, description, author } = doc.data();
        boards.push({
            key: doc.id,
            title,
            description,
            author
        });
    });
    this.setState({
        boards,
        isLoading: false
    })
    console.log(boards);
}
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {
                this.state.boards.maps((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <ListItem
                            key={i}
                            title={item.title}
                            leftIcon={{name: 'book', type: 'font-awesome'}}
                            onPress={() => {
                                this.props.navigation.navigate('BoardDetails', {
                                    boardKey: `${JSON.stringify(item.key)}`,
                                });
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                })
            }
        </View>
    );
```

O erro está na linha: this.state.boards.maps Onde o erro informa que o maps não é uma função.
Sou iniciante e não estou conseguindo achar o erro, já fiz todo tipo de troca, pode ser uma besteira, mas não encontro! Alguém poderia me dar uma luz? Ficarei muito grato!

Answer (score 0):

A função `map` funciona apenas com arrays. Se ele informa que map não é uma função, significa que o componente que você está tentando percorrer não é um array, pode ser qualquer outra coisa.

Antes de usar o `this.state.boards.map` já tentou fazer um `console.log(this.state.boards)`? O primeiro elemento deve ser um array, não um Object.

Na linha do `this.setState({boards, isLoading: false})`, faça isso:

```
this.setState({boards: boards, isLoading: false})
```

Caso ainda não tenha sucesso, tente usar `Object.keys(this.state.boards).map` ou `Object.keys(this.state.boards[0]).map`.